# show glyphicon based on value in angular

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, express

my controller :

```
.controller('BlogController', function(blogFactory, $routeParams, $scope){

    var that=this;

    stat=false;

    this.checkbookmark = function(bId){
    console.log(bId)
    blogFactory.checkBookmark(bId, function(response){
        console.log(response)
        if(response == "bookmarked"){
            that.stat = true;  
        }
        else{
            that.stat = false;  
        }
    })
}
```

my html code :

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController as blogCtrl">

    <div class="row" ng-repeat="chunk in blogCtrl.blogs | filter: filter_name  | orderBy:'-created_at'  | groupBy: 3">


        <div class="outerbox1 col-sm-4" ng-repeat="blog in chunk" >
            <div class="innerbox3"  ng-init="blogCtrl.checkbookmark(blog._id)">
                <br>
                <div> > READ MORE 
                    <a ng-if="blogCtrl.stat" ng-href="#" ng-click="blogCtrl.removebookmark(blog._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart pull-right">{{blogCtrl.stat}}</a>
                    <a ng-if="!blogCtrl.stat" ng-href="#" ng-click="blogCtrl.addbookmark(blog._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty pull-right">{{blogCtrl.stat}}</a> 
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

service factory :

```
  factory.checkBookmark = function(info, callback){
    $http({
        url:'api/check_bookmark_blog',
        method:'POST',
        headers:{'x-access-token': token},
        params:{'user_id': userid},
        data:{'blog_id':info}
    }).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        callback(data)
    })
}
```

I want to show glyphicon based on the value of **stat**

I have 6 blogs, first 3 are bookmarked and next 3 are not.

The problem i'm getting is that the **stat** value is always set according to the last bookmark and hence it is always false / true (based on the condition of last blog).

How to resolve this issue and set glyphicon respective to value of stat for each blog?

Comment: try using ng-class in your innerbox3 element

Comment: @SahilChauhan it doesnt work... it goes in an infinite loop.

Comment: hmm.. can you give me more code that where your service is set?

Comment: @SahilChauhan please check the updated ques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are multiple ways of implementing it.

You can either store the `true/false` values in either an `array` or you can run a `function` every time which returns `true/false`.

#### Using function which returns `true/false` values:

Modify your `checkbookmark` function to return `true/false` values as follows,

Controller code:

```
.controller('BlogController', function (blogFactory, $routeParams, $scope) {

    this.checkbookmark = function (bId) {
        blogFactory.checkBookmark(bId, function (response) {
            if(response == "bookmarked"){
                return true; // returns true if bookmarked 
            } else {
                return false;  // returns false if not bookmarked
            }
        });
    };

});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController as blogCtrl">

    <div class="row" ng-repeat="chunk in blogCtrl.blogs | filter: filter_name  | orderBy:'-created_at'  | groupBy: 3 track by $index">
        <div class="outerbox1 col-sm-4" ng-repeat="blog in chunk track by $index" >
                <!-- removed ng-init here -->
                <div class="innerbox3">
                <br>
                <div> > READ MORE 
                    <a ng-if="blogCtrl.checkbookmark(blog._id)" ng-href="#" ng-click="blogCtrl.removebookmark(blog._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart pull-right">{{blogCtrl.stat}}</a>
                    <a ng-if="!blogCtrl.checkbookmark(blog._id)" ng-href="#" ng-click="blogCtrl.addbookmark(blog._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty pull-right">{{blogCtrl.stat}}</a> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

#### Using an array:

Store the `true/false` values in an array and access them in `html` using 
`track by $index` in your `ng-repeat` clause.

Controller code:

```
.controller('BlogController', function (blogFactory, $routeParams, $scope) {

    this.stat = [];  // initializing array
    this.checkbookmark = function (bId) {
        blogFactory.checkBookmark(bId, function (response) {
            if(response == "bookmarked"){
                this.stat.push(true);  
            } else {
                this.stat.push(false);  
            }
        });
    };

});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController as blogCtrl">

    <div class="row" ng-repeat="chunk in blogCtrl.blogs | filter: filter_name  | orderBy:'-created_at'  | groupBy: 3 track by $index">
            <!-- note the usage of track by $index in ng-repeat -->
            <div class="outerbox1 col-sm-4" ng-repeat="blog in chunk track by $index" >
            <div class="innerbox3"  ng-init="blogCtrl.checkbookmark(blog._id)">
                <br>
                <div> > READ MORE 
                    <a ng-if="blogCtrl.stat[$index]" ng-href="#" ng-click="blogCtrl.removebookmark(blog._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart pull-right">{{blogCtrl.stat}}</a>
                    <a ng-if="!blogCtrl.stat[$index]" ng-href="#" ng-click="blogCtrl.addbookmark(blog._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty pull-right">{{blogCtrl.stat}}</a> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Hope this solves the problem.

I exactly don't know which implementation is better or any other implementations for the same. May be other folks in stackoverflow could suggest.